# Test a string ($text) to see if it contains numeric digits

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to test a string to see if it has any numeric digits within it. I try this code and nothing happens:

```
<?php

function hasNumber($text) {

$length = strlen ($text); 
for ($index=0; $index<$length; $index++){
    if (is_numeric($text[$index])){
    echo "The name: ".$_POST['text']." is not numeric!";
    return true;
    }else{
    echo "The name: ".$_POST['text']." is numeric!";
    return false;  
    }
        }
    if (isset($_POST['submitText'])){
    hasNumber($_POST['text']);
    }
    }

?>
<form action = 'valid.php' method ='POST'>
<table>
    Enter Name :<input name="text"><br>

    <tr><td><input type="submit" type="text" name="submitText" value="Validate text"></td></tr>
```

Comment: Do you want to find out if the string *contains* numeric digits or if the entire string represents a numeric value?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
function hasNumber($text) {
    return preg_match("/\d/", $text);
}
```

Or this if you want a boolean rather than the number of matches:

```
function hasNumber($text) {
    return preg_match("/\d/", $text) > 0;
}
```

Comment: preg_match returns the number of matches, whereas hasNumber should return true or false. should return with `=== 1`. Also there's no need for the square brackets.

Comment: im using this for text validation I need the code to say whether it has any numeric characters within it. it seems that its not reading any of the code after the function is declared??

Comment: @Jacob Since anything above 0 equates to `true`, it won't matter much if it returns an int or a boolean in this case. `=== 1` won't work anyway since it might have more than one matches. `> 0` could be used if a boolean is needed. Thanks for the brackets tip, though. I wasn't sure so I included it.

Comment: @Tom What exactly do you mean with "It's not reading any code"?

Comment: I put a echo to test whether it is being implemented just after the function and it doesn't, so i am assuming the code is not being implemented after the function is declared.

Comment: The function isn't anything special. Are you sure the function's closed properly? (Could you perhaps paste your code through pastebin.com?)

Comment: @TVK preg_match will only ever have 1 match or 0 matches.

Answer (score 0):

You could use preg_match with a regex for the digits:

```
preg_match('([0-9]+)', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out if the entire string represents a numeric value:

```
if (is_numeric($_POST['text'])) {
```

If you want to find out if the string contains one or more numeric digis:

```
if (preg_match('[^.0-9]', $_POST['text']) > 0) {
```

Comment: By the way, if using a regular expression with preg_match, think about if you need to allow comma and/or decimal points in the number. Eg. 1,324.76 might be a valid number.